# Import more than one class from node_modules

Tags: javascript, npm, ecmascript-6

I'm currently developing a package, and inside my package repository I have the following structure:

```
src
  - Requests.js
  - Constants.js
package.json
```

Inside my `package.json`, I have the following:

```
{
    "name": "package-name",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "src/Requests"
}
```

Then inside my project, I do the following to retrieve my module:

```
import Requests from 'package-name';
```

Now what I'm trying to achieve is to import the `Constants` class from the package. However, when I do the following, I get a compiled error that it cannot locate the class.

```
import Constants from 'package-name/Constants';
```

To get it working, I have to do but I don't want to have the `/src` in the import path.

```
import Constants from 'package-name/src/Constants';
```

I've tried to change the `main` in my `package.json` to the directory, but it's still not working:

```
"main": "src/"
```

Comment: So `import { Requests, Constants } from 'package-name';` doesn't work?

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat No it does not work :[

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, this is not a bug, just how node imports are handled by your bundler. There are many solutions to this problem, here are a couple:

The most user friendly is to have your publish command copy those components to the root directory and then publish. That way you'll be able to import like you say, `import Constants from 'package-name/Constants'`. It's only slightly inconvenient for you as a developer but a script should be able to clean up after the publish command succeeds.

An alternate solution is to have a third file, maybe call it `index.js` that looks somewhat like this:

```
import Requests from './Requests';
import Constants from './Constants';

export default {
   Requests,
   Constants,
};
```

This will allow you to import like this (don't forget to change your `package.json` to have `"main": "src/index.js"`):

```
import { Requests, Constants } from 'package-name';
```

The only reason I would shy away from this approach is that when this import statement is handled by the bundler, ALL components are imported, even if you only need one of them. It could make your bundle larger if your library contains many different components.

Comment: Is it not possible to simply specify the root directory in the `package.json`? So when I do `package-name`, it would point to the `src` directory?

Comment: Not that I know

Comment: Some people will write their distributable files to a `dist` folder or `lib` folder and then import from `package-name/lib/Component`. Not too crazy, less ugly for development, not as nice for users